# VBA Access 2013 form: how to refresh?

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access

I have a form *Overview* with a table that gets its data from a database. I would like to add a line to that database and update my table in *Overview*. I created a button in *Overview* which opens another form *InputForm* (that pops up in front of *Overview*). In VBA, I wrote some code that adds the data to the database using a query and then closes *InputForm*. When *InputForm* closes, *Overview* becomes visible again. Now, I would like to see the table in *Overview* updated with the new data. The problem is that it only updates when I click another button in *Overview* or when I close and reopen the form.

I tried the `GotFocus`, `Activate`, `Click`... events to `Refresh` the form but I guess that the form does not lose focus or is not deactivated when *InputForm* is opened so these events of course never happen. I also tried to `Refresh` *Overview* from within the *InputForm*. I also tried to find the `Activate` or `Deactivate` functions but they appear nowhere. I honestly don't know how to update the table in the *Overview* form.

EDIT:

*Overview*

```
Private Sub btnOpenInputForm_Click()

DoCmd.OpenForm FormName:="InputForm", OpenArgs:=0 & "," & 0

End Sub
```

*InputForm*

```
Private Sub btnAddRecord_Click()

'Read data from the input fields 
'CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT..."

DoCmd.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried the `.Requery` method of the form control bound to your table?

Comment: See my comment on the answer of Unhandled Exception.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, then your form named `Overview` is bound to the same table which will be a record added to by a button which also is on that form.

So the code to add the new record runs in the `Click` event of that button, right?

So then you would have to call `Me.Requery` after adding the record (The `Me` keyword is a reference to the form in that case).

## Edit:

Regarding your new information I added this, showing how to call your InputForm as a modal dialog and read out the values in case the user didn't cancel it.

This would be your calling procedure:

```
Private Sub btnOpenInputForm_Click()
    Const INPUT_FORM_NAME As String = "InputForm"

    'Call the form as a modal dialog
    DoCmd.OpenForm FormName:=INPUT_FORM_NAME, OpenArgs:=0 & "," & 0, WindowMode:=acDialog

    'If the user cancelled the dialog, it is not loaded any more.
    'So exit the sub (or maybe do some other stuff)
    If Not CurrentProject.AllForms(INPUT_FORM_NAME).IsLoaded Then
        Debug.Print "The user cancelled the dialog"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'You can now check a value in the dialog
    If IsNull(Forms(INPUT_FORM_NAME).MyTextBox.Value) Then
        Debug.Print "Null in the control"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Or read a value into a variable
    Dim myVariable As String
    myVariable = Forms(INPUT_FORM_NAME).MyTextBox.Value

    'Close the dialog form now
    DoCmd.Close A_FORM, INPUT_FORM_NAME

    'Build and execute your sql here, like you already did in the dialog form before
    'CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT..."
    Debug.Print "User entered: ", myVariable

    'And finally requery the form
    Me.Requery
End Sub
```

In the dialog form ("InputForm")

- the `Click` procedure of the OK-button has to call `Me.Visible = False` to just hide the dialog.
- the `Click` procedure of the Cancel-button has to call `DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name` to close the dialog.

Comment: The `Click` event opens "InputForm" so the code to add the new record is in that form. `Me` therefore refers to "InputForm" and not to "Overview". I try to move the sql-query to the `Click` event so that I can use `Me.Requery`.

Comment: How does the click event open the „InputForm“? By VBA also? Is it opened as a modal dialog?

Comment: I edited my question with some code to show how I open the form.

Comment: Ok, be aware that you would have to call your 'InputForm' as a modal dialog to force the calling code to wait until this dialog finished. If you never used modal dialogs, it is a bit tricky. I will prepare another answer for you in a few minutes showing how to do this.

Comment: I'll have a try (in a few days) and let you know the results. Thanks for your help.